# Re-instantiate AngularJS code in console after amendment / debug in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

This is a strange question, and I know this is possible as I have done it before, I have just forgotten the syntax! Say for instance I have an angularJS app and I have named this in the code myAngularApp, so in the app.js file I have something like this:

```
angular.module('myAngularApp', [
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngAnimate'
])
```

Now I have amended some scripts and HTML in the Chrome Dev tools and now I want to reboot / re-instantiate the angular code without a browser refresh, I used to do this in the console by typing something like...

```
angular.bootstrap('myAngularApp')
```

but this gives me an error like so:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'getAttribute' in myAngularApp
 at new App (chrome-extension://aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj/ng-inspector.js:967:25)
    at Function.NGI.App.App.bootstrap (chrome-extension://aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj/ng-inspector.js:1031:16)
    at Object.window.angular.bootstrap (chrome-extension://aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj/ng-inspector.js:1512:12)
    at <anonymous>:2:9
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

But I am unsure if this is an error with a chrome extension rather than my statement `angular.bootstrap('myAngularApp')`? Is angular.bootstrap the correct way to re-instantiate / reboot my angular app in the Dev Tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that removing the **[ng-inspector for AngularJS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspector-for-angularj/aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj)** plugin from Chrome removed the error, however I am unsure if `angular.bootstrap('myAngularApp')` is re-instantiating the app